# Recurrence relation . Please tell me where I went wrong

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I was asked to solve the following recurrence relation in my homework question , T(n) = T(√n) + T(n - √n) + cn

This is how I solved the same and also got the right answer. But there is an obvious error in my solving. Please point out how to correct my wrong step.

For all n > 4 we have , √n < (n-√n)

Thus the term T(n - √n) will move slowly towards T(1) thus contributing to the height of the recurrence tree.

By simple mathematics we can say that after √n iterations the term T(n - √n) will finally be T(1). (This is where I went wrong. I had thought the terms will reduce as follows, T(n - √n) , T(n - 2√n), T(n - 3√n) but they dont)

Thus the height of the above tree is √n.

Also cost of operation at each level is at the most cn.

Thus total cost of the operation is √n * cn.

Thus the running time of the algorithm is O(n√n)

Comment: "By simple mathematics" - wrong :) just do a *simple* substitution... in the next recursive step n is n - √n

Comment: ya I realised my mistake :P. But now with the correct substitution I am not able to find the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Your general idea is correct, height of tree is at most √n as you mentioned, but the wrong part in your answer is : "Also cost of operation at each level is at the most cn".

The width of tree grows by factor of two in each level for upto depth log log n, (means up to some point, width of tree grows very fast), and in each vertex in a specific row you have to do O(n) operation, which means in each row you have more operation than cn (in average).

If you want to approach this problem is not bad to consider the following case:

n=2<sup>2<sup>s</sup></sup>, and see the behavior of your function.

Comment: Even the height of the tree wont be √n, right ? The term will reduce as follows:- T(n - √n),  T(n - √n - √[n - √n])....  instead of T(n - √n) , T(n - 2√n)....

Comment: @user2753551, yes you are right, I didn't calculate the value (you should compute recursion tree exactly), but in the last nodes is O(n) so it does not effect the total value (very much). By the way I think using 2^2^s as n, is simpler to come up to a solution, and at first suppose your recursion depth is √n then try to enhance your answer.